# After upgrade to Magento 2.4 I get "Class configured_block_cache does not exist"

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Error in question:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class configured_block_cache does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class configured_block_cache does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#5 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#6 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#8 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#9 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#10 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/PageFactory.php:56]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php:74]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\View->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#13 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#14 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#15 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#16 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#17 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#18 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#19 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php:44]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php:306]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php:167]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#23 Magento\Backend\App\Router\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#24 Magento\Backend\App\Router\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#25 Magento\Backend\App\Router\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/App/Router/Interceptor.php:26]
#26 Magento\Backend\App\Router\Interceptor->match() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:115]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
</pre>
```

I have narrowed it down to `magento/module-csp` that sets the `Magento\Csp\Model\BlockCache` as `configured_block_cache` and therefore sets it in the `generated/metadata/frontend.php` (and others)

Excerpt from `vendor/magento/module-csp/etc/di.xml:93`:

```
...
<type name="Magento\Csp\Model\BlockCache">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="cache" xsi:type="object">configured_block_cache</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
...
```

Excerpt from `generated/metadata/frontend.php`:

```
...
'Magento\\Csp\\Model\\BlockCache' =>
array (
  'cache' =>
  array (
    '_i_' => 'configured_block_cache',
  ),
  'dynamicCollector' =>
  array (
    '_i_' => 'Magento\\Csp\\Model\\Collector\\DynamicCollector',
  ),
  'serializer' =>
  array (
    '_i_' => 'Magento\\Framework\\Serialize\\Serializer\\Json',
  ),
),
...
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error though.

I have searched my database for multiple forms of the word cache and/or csp

Anybody else experiencing something similar and know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue when upgrading from Magento 2.3.4 to 2.4. After looking at an existing Magento 2.4 environment I noticed the following lines missing in 'app/etc/di.xml':

```
<virtualType name="configured_block_cache" type="Magento\Framework\App\Cache">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="cacheIdentifier" xsi:type="string">block_html</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="cache" xsi:type="object">configured_block_cache</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\SqlVersionProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="supportedVersionPatterns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="MySQL-8" xsi:type="string">^8\.0\.</item>
            <item name="MySQL-5.7" xsi:type="string">^5\.7\.</item>
            <item name="MariaDB-(10.2-10.4)" xsi:type="string">^10\.[2-4]\.</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="blockVariables" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="secureRenderer" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer\Proxy</item>
            <item name="escaper" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Escaper</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

The error will be resolved after adding these lines and clearing the cache. I'm not sure why these lines are not added when upgrading to 2.4, but are when installing a clean installation.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thanks for figuring it out.